# Android application connecting to a public server database

Tags: android, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I'm creating an application in Android, and I also have a virtual server in Amazon Web Services, because I'm trying to connect to a database hosted in there from my Android application; I'd like to know how could I connect to the AWS database (Microsoft SQL Server), I understand that the servers in AWS are visible publicly, but I'm lost here, Could you provide me some guidance on this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create a web service layer between your Android app and your back-end database. That way, your Android app talks to the web service via the HTTP protocol, and the web service (running on a web server with access to your SQL Server) talks to the database. This is the most common method for achieving the database connectivity you need.

You create your web services using whichever web technology you are most comfortable with; .NET, PHP, ColdFusion, or whatever. So-called RESTful web services are a nice way to do this. [You can read about building RESTful web services with .NET here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx). Hope it helps. Good luck with your app.

Comment: this.  i use a .net webservice to return a json string from my SQL Server database.  Granted, my solution is not on AWS but a local server.